# Python: From outside Class access to variable in method other than __self__(init)

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

There is an example at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm
and one thing I don't understand:

```
class Dialog(Toplevel):

    ...

        self.result = None

...

class MyDialog(Dialog):

    def apply(self):
        first = int(self.e1.get())
        second = int(self.e2.get())
        self.result = first, second

d = MyDialog(root)
print d.result
```

They access `self.result` inside the `apply` method by referring to `d.result`.

I tried to reconstruct this with my own simple example:

```
class Mother(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.result = None
  def apply(self):
    pass

class Class(Mother):
  def apply(self):
    self.result = "hello"

d = Class()
print d.result
```

The output of `print d.result` is None instead of "hello"

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never called `d.apply()` to set `result` to "hello".

Comment: To be more verbose, the big difference between the presented class hierarchy and that lies behind `Toplevel` is that it is hard to say by heart what `Toplevel` does. If we can assume that there is somewhere a call inside `Toplevel.__init__()` which calls `self.apply()`, we have found the difference.